# Approval Process - Send Later Steps to Record Owner's Manager

Tags: approval-process

I'm trying to build an approval process for Opportunities that uses the following steps:
Step 1: send to Finance for evaluation
Step 2: send to record owner's manager for approval

The problem I have is if I select Manager as the approver in step 2, it sends it to the Finance person's manager and not the record owner's manager. How can I get step 2 to go to the Opportunity owner's manager?

Comment: apex?  setNextApproverIds(new Set<Id>{...}) http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_process_example.htm

Comment: Definitely not going to use that hammer. Plus, since it is step 2, I don't think I can get it to see Step 1 approval and then assign the Step 2 approver.